# Python function always returns false when comparing to ints

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from pip.backwardcompat import raw_input
from PFD import *


def getInput():
    try:
        n = raw_input("Please enter the file size: ")
        int(n)
        print(str(n))
        order = raw_input("Please enter a Fib Order [3/4]: ")
        int(order)
    except ValueError:
        getInput()

    if order == 3:
        Fib.three(n)
    elif order == 4:
        Fib.four(n)
    else:
        print("You did something wrong, idiot.")
        getInput()


getInput();
```

So this is the problem. No matter what I do, it tells me I did something wrong and calls me an idiot. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your line

```
int(order)
```

needs to be assigned back to the order variable like so:

```
order = int(order)
```

edit: As alKid pointed out, the same for n:

```
n = int(n)
```

Comment: Or maybe `order = int(raw_input("Please enter a Fib Order [3/4]: "))`

Answer (score 2):

In python, integers are immutable. Hence, when you do `int(n)`, it won't change the type of the variable in-place. You have to do `n = int(n)`, or wrap `int()` around the `raw_input(...` call.

This is the same for `order`